# bootstrap row going above another in mobile view in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, row

i have created an html section in bootstrap, which contains a container and two main rows, the code is like below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  .addonscard {
    width: 100%;
    height: 181px;
    padding: 2%;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
  }
  
  .addonsimage {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    color: #30ac15;
    border: 1px solid #30ac15;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 2px 12px 2px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    color: #30ac15;
    border: 1px solid #30ac15;
  }
  
  .addonsdesc {
    font-size: 13px
  }
  
  #showmore {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .clearme {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
</style>


<section class="addons">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="addonscard">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="addonsimage" src="test1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <h4>This is Heading</h4>
              <p>Price</p>
              <a href="" class="add-on-add-unit">+ Add</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <p class="addonsdesc">Standard photography at best value to turn make lifetime memories from your party. Photographer will be available for maximum 3 hours. 150 - 200 soft copies will be delivered through CD within 10 working days. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="addonscard">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="addonsimage" src="test2.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <h4>This is Heading</h4>
              <p>Price</p>
              <a href="" class="add-on-add-unit">+ Add</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <p class="addonsdesc">Standard photography at best value to turn make lifetime memories from your party. Photographer will be available for maximum 3 hours. 150 - 200 soft copies will be delivered through CD within 10 working days. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearme"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10" id="showmore">
        <a href="#" class="showmore">+ Show more add-ons</a>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

now the problem is

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10" id="showmore">
    <a href="#" class="showmore">+ Show more add-ons</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

this row is going above the first row in mobile view, i have tried using mobile query to adjust but still its not moving down, can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: Remove height (181px) from ".addonscard" class and try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove height (181px) from ".addonscard" class in CSS and try :

```
.addonscard {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; // height is updated from 181px to auto..
  padding: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;}
```

Comment: Yes, it will work for sure. Actually you fixed ".addonscard" class height due to which you were facing this issue. Now height is auto and adjust as per available content and screen size.

Comment: If your problem is resolved from my code/solution and also you satisfy, please accept my answers. So that it will help others too in this type of query and update my reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

set height for rows and set float right for them!

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .row{
  height:fit-content;
  float:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  .addonscard {
    width: 100%;
    height: 181px;
    padding: 2%;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
  }
  
  .addonsimage {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    color: #30ac15;
    border: 1px solid #30ac15;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 2px 12px 2px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .add-on-add-unit {
    color: #30ac15;
    border: 1px solid #30ac15;
  }
  
  .addonsdesc {
    font-size: 13px
  }
  
  #showmore {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .clearme {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
</style>


<section class="addons">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="addonscard">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="addonsimage" src="test1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <h4>This is Heading</h4>
              <p>Price</p>
              <a href="" class="add-on-add-unit">+ Add</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <p class="addonsdesc">Standard photography at best value to turn make lifetime memories from your party. Photographer will be available for maximum 3 hours. 150 - 200 soft copies will be delivered through CD within 10 working days. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="addonscard">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="addonsimage" src="test2.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <h4>This is Heading</h4>
              <p>Price</p>
              <a href="" class="add-on-add-unit">+ Add</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <p class="addonsdesc">Standard photography at best value to turn make lifetime memories from your party. Photographer will be available for maximum 3 hours. 150 - 200 soft copies will be delivered through CD within 10 working days. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearme"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10" id="showmore">
        <a href="#" class="showmore">+ Show more add-ons</a>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```